# Convert iPhone application logo to Android

Tags: android, ios, android-studio

I'm working on creating an Android application based on an already created iPhone app. I have a bunch of app icons from the iPhone application that end in '@xx.png' (x being a number).

I know this has something to do with the resolution of the image, but do I have to do anything regarding converting them into vectors/renaming them to a certain standard in Android?

Comment: Hello Elliott. Were you able to get help from my answer?

Comment: @Ishaan kinda/sorta. Seems that I should be putting these assets in Mipmap folders instead of Drawable folders (from what I've read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the pretty good practice, but in the end, if you don't have separated dimensions for Android too, then, somehow you can considerate the ratio like this:

**@1x** -> **mdpi** *(the baseline)*

**@2x** -> **xhdpi**

**@3x** -> **xxhdpi**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tool that does what you need, just take the best image with the best resolution from iOS images, and use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) link to generate the ic_launcher for android.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, when you are inserting images or icons into the `drawables` folder of Android, you need to ensure the following:

1. The names of the images/icons cannot contain capital letters.
2. The file type of the image/icon is either `.png` or `.jpg`. `.svg` is not allowed.
3. You also can't have symbols like `-`, `_`, or `@`.

You can also refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@AkhilDad/a-designers-guide-for-naming-android-assets-f790359d11e5) about **naming Android Assets.** And [this website](http://appiconmaker.co/) allows you to **make your own app icons.**
I hope this answers your question.